# How to get label name in Autocad file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, autocad, autodesk

I think it is simple to do this but i dont know how to start? I want to get layer name or label name in the autocad file using c#. I search the forums but i really find anything valuable. I found the ObjectARX and AutoLisp, but i dont find any tutorial about theese API's. So, i want to simple example about the reach autocad file.

Comment: Open Design Alliance has .NET APIs for reading AutoCAD files as well
http://www.opendesign.com/the_oda_platform/tdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the ObjectARX SDK from the [official site](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=123112&id=785550) it contains many sample projects to get you started.  You will need to have some AutoCAD knowledge to understand the structure of the .dwg database as exposed by the API.  Be prepared to invest significant time in the project.

If you just are looking for a simple one time dump of the data in a .dwg file ask your local drafter as there is a command in the AutoCAD UI for doing this known as the Data Extraction Wizard.

Another answer on stackoverflow recommend [this book chapter](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/11/11180222/DOWNLOAD/9781118022214-BC01.pdf) as a way to understand the AutoCAD database connection features.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple as follows:

```
[CommandMethod("LayerIterator")]
public static void LayerIterator_Method()
{
    Database database = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
    using (Transaction transaction = database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        SymbolTable symTable = (SymbolTable)transaction.GetObject(database.LayerTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
        foreach (ObjectId id in symTable)
        {
            LayerTableRecord symbol = (LayerTableRecord)transaction.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);

            //TODO: Access to the symbol
            MgdAcApplication.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.WriteMessage(string.Format("\nName: {0}", symbol.Name));
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Details can be found from http://spiderinnet1.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/autocad-net-iterate-through-layer-table.html